# Why isn't the USER declared in my Dockerfile reflected in the ENTRYPOINT script?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to fix some tests we're running on Jenkins with Docker, but the script that the `ENTRYPOINT` in my Dockerfile points to keeps running as root, even though I set the `USER` in the Dockerfile. This works fine on my local machine but not when running on our Jenkins box.

I've tried running `su` within my entrypoint script to make sure that the rest of the script run as the correct user, but they still run as root.

So my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext libgettextpo-dev

ARG DOCKER_UID # set to 2000 in docker-compose file
ARG ENV=prod
ENV ENV=${ENV}
ARG WORKERS=2
ENV WORKERS=${WORKERS}

RUN useradd -u ${DOCKER_UID} -ms /bin/bash app
RUN chmod -R 777 /home/app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN chown -R app:app /code
RUN mkdir /platform
RUN chown -R app:app /platform
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN whoami # outputs `root`
USER app
RUN whoami # outputs `app`

RUN .docker/deploy/install_requirements.sh $ENV # runs as `app`

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT [".docker/deploy/start.sh", "$ENV"]
```

and my `start.sh` looks like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ENV=$1

echo "USER"
echo `whoami`

echo Running migrations...
python manage.py migrate

mkdir -p static
chmod -R 0755 static


cd /code/

if [ "$ENV" == "performance-dev" ];
then
    /home/app/.local/bin/uwsgi --ini .docker/deploy/uwsgi.ini -p 4 --uid app
else
    /home/app/.local/bin/uwsgi --ini .docker/deploy/uwsgi.ini --uid app
fi
```

but the

```sh
echo "USER"
echo `whoami`
```

outputs:

```
USER
root
```

which causes commands later in the script the fail as they're the wrong user.

I'd except the output to be

```
USER
app
```

and my understanding is that this issue is typically resolved by setting  the `USER` command in the Dockerfile, but I do that and it looks like it is switching user when running the Dockerfile itself.

**Edit**

The issue was with my docker-compose configuration. My docker-compose config looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  service:
    user: "${DOCKER_UID}:${DOCKER_UID}"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        - ENV=prod
        - DOCKER_UID=2000
```

`DOCKER_UID` is a variable set on my local machine but not on the Jenkins box, so I set it to 2000 in the override file

Comment: Is that your whole entrypoint script?  You're not using a `docker run -u 0` option or anything similar to override this at container startup time?

Comment: It wasn't, I've updated it, but you did lead me to the answer! It was because I configured my docker-compose incorrectly and was setting the `user` variable to an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having, as David Maze pointed out in the comments, was that I was setting the user when actually building the container, via my docker-compose file. I had set the `user` param to `${DOCKER_UID}`, which was never actually set anywhere, so it was defaulting to an empty string. Setting it to `2000` fixed my issue.